# How to prevent VS Code from forcing its file extension on me?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

When I save a file in VS Code, if I haven't previously told VS Code what type of file it is, it refuses to cede control over the file extension to me, and insists that whatever it defaulted to or whatever it inferred to be the file type *is* the file type.  This is sub-optimal UX. Is there any way to turn it this obtuseness off?

[image: VS Code's file extension usurpation]

I shouldn't have to back up out of the Save dialog so that I can again have the control to choose the file extension.  I don't want to tab 17 times to get to the list in the Save dialog to choose a different file type.  And I definitely don't want to use the mouse  to select a different file type from the list either just so I can type the correct file extension.  I just want VS Code to stay in its lane and let me type whatever I darn well please as the file extension, and neither tell me that it's the master and I'm the slave, nor passive-agressively tack on its preferred file extension on the end of what I type.  (I've seen both behaviors.)

Surely there must be a way to do this.  I can't be the only person unwilling let my editor to make decisions for me.

Comment: Fixed and released for insiders - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102713. You should be able to test & verify it with https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/.

Comment: Hallelujah!!!!!